# When does "kill" mean "to put to death" and when "to destroy"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrases

In most dictionaries, it is said that only in phrases like "kill [something]" (ex: kill an idea) may the word "kill" mean "to destroy".

When followed by "somebody", it usually refers to its original meaning "to put to death" (there are also some other meanings like "to cause pain")

Do you agree with this? If you don't, could you show some examples where "kill" means "to destroy somebody" (to ruin one's spirit, career, or life)"?

Comment: [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/103361).

Comment: The OED is behind a paywall.

Comment: The context will reveal the colloquial meaning. Only the context and speaker.

Answer (score 3):

As with many words, the word "kill" has a literal meaning and can also have a symbolic meaning.

Yes, if I read, "The former king was led to the guillotine where he was killed", I would take the word "kill" literally. The life of a living being was ended.

If someone uses the word "kill" referring to something that is not alive, the meaning must be symbolic. Like if someone says, "The company killed the project", well clearly a "project" is not alive and so cannot be literally killed. I would understand this to mean that they ended the project before it's completion.

You certainly can use the word "kill" to refer to people in a non-literal way. For example there is a common idiom, "Please, you're killing me!" Someone might say this and mean the word "kill" literally, like if the other person was doing something dangerous and in imminent danger of ending his life. But people often say this to mean, "You are causing me problems" or "you are annoying me". For example someone might say, "I had to get a divorce. My marriage was killing me." They probably don't mean that it was literally ending their life, but rather that it was extremely unpleasant.

"Kill" can be used to mean things having nothing to do with destruction. Like there is an idiom, "He killed the ball", meaning he kicked or hit the ball very hard. Or if someone tells a very funny joke, a listener might say, "Oh, you're killing me!" It can even mean practically the opposite of physical destruction. Like if you said, "Wow, Sally is a great singer! She killed that song!", you mean that she sang it very well.

I'm sure this isn't a complete list of non-literal meanings. Like with any word, to tell what it means in a given example you have to look at the context. If the literal meaning makes sense and there's no reason to suspect a non-literal meaning, I'd generally assume that the literal meaning is what is meant. Otherwise, see what might make sense in context.

Comment: I often say 'you're killing me!' to mean 'you are amusing me (e.g. with a joke) so much that I might die laughing', and I think this is often said with sarcastic intent (i.e. what has been said is not really funny at all).

Comment: A soldering flux, 'killed spirits', is made by adding zinc to dilute hydrochloric acid until no more hydrogen is produced. The chemical name for the result is zinc chloride solution.

Comment: You can also "kill time", to do something to spend time while waiting...

Comment: As a youngster I got a big insight when I saw _quelle_ in Chaucer, e.g. _The dokès crieden as men wold hem quelle_.

Comment: @fev "kill time" An interesting example, I guess that's sort of like destroy in the sense of waste.

Comment: @Jay Not really waste. It means to occupy yourself with something so that you make it pass. You fill time with an activity that makes it "go away", or something like that?

Comment: @fev Yes. If we're trying to nail down the meaning of "kill time", you're correct. I was just trying to relate it to the literal meaning. Sort of kind of like "destroying" time.